# Problem using java.time.LocalDate as process-variable in jBPM - Business Central

Tags: datetimepicker, jbpm

I'd like to use a process-variable to retrieve and store only date, no time information. Therefore I've defined a java.time.LocalDate variable in my process. Then in a taskform, where user should be able to enter a date, I entered a form-control of type DatePicker and unchecked its "show time" property. My problem: the entered date isn't stored in the process-variable. If I check the "show time" property, then the user is being asked for a daytime too and the Date (without time information) is stored in the variable. How can I ask only for a Date and store only a Date?
Another question: I'm using the jBPM-server-distribution 7.36.0.Final and Dates in the DatePicker-Control have the format mm/dd/YYYY. Would it be possible to show Dates with the format dd/mm/YYYY?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi!

Did you get any answer? I'm facing the same problem and spent hours to get it work without success. My Date variable always gets null when the "Show Time" is not checked. But I do not need the user to enter the time.
I'm upgraded to 7.73.0-Final but all the same.

TIA

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't received an answer to my problem yet :-(